# hibernate criteria query select for update order by

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have the following code that uses Hibernate Criteria API.

```
    List<?> results = getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(PersonEvent.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq(STATUS, EventStatus.NEW))
            .addOrder( Order.asc("sequence") )
           .setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
            .setMaxResults(maxResults).list();
```

It generates the following sql

```
select
        * 
    from
        ( /* criteria query */ select
            this_.SEQUENCE as SEQUENCE0_0_,
            this_1_.CREATED_UTC as CREATED3_0_0_,
            this_1_.UPDATED_UTC as UPDATED5_0_0_,
            this_1_.STATUS as STATUS0_0_,
            this_.PERSONID as PERSONID1_0_ 
        from
            ACT.PERSON_EVENT this_ 
        inner join
            ACT.EVENT this_1_ 
                on this_.SEQUENCE=this_1_.SEQUENCE 
        where
            this_1_.STATUS='NEW' 
            order by this_1_.SEQUENCE) 
    where
        rownum <= 50 for update
```

Which results in

```
ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
02014. 00000 -  "cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."
```

I have two tables ACT.EVENT (parent) and ACT.PERSON_EVENT (child) modeled using hibernate table per subclass inheritance with one-one relationship. So entity class PersonEvent extends abstract entity class Event.

```
ACT.EVENT
-SEQUENCE (PK)
-STATUS
-CREATED_UTC
-UPDATED_UTC

ACT.PERSON_EVENT
-SEQUENCE (PK, FK)
-PERSONID
```

How can I write this same query with order by using Criteria API.

Comment: remove setMaxResults(maxResults) from query, as I dont think its possible to select for update with rownum in where condition. If you can't remove this then you have to use either HQL or Native query instead of Criteria